# Which automation tool can be used to automate a desktop application whose frontend is developed on MS Access

Tags: automated-testing, tools

.. I am working on an application which is developed on MS Access platform. Its a desktop application and in MS Access the executable file is created with .ADP extension. I had tried some of the tools for the automation but those tools take the file of .exe extension. Is there any tool through which I can automate the frontend of the application. The coding is done on VBA language.
I will be very thankful if anyone can help me on this part.

Comment: I did a quick web search and found a hit at the SmartBear TestComplete user forum, where someone asked about testing an ADP file app. You may want to submit your specific question there. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

- [AccUnit](http://accunit.access-codelib.net), a specialized Unit-Test framework for Microsoft Access.
- TestComplete, [it enables to test MS Access applications](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56886/).

---

Also look at the [similar topic at StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400/best-way-to-test-a-ms-access-application).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for HP QTP give it a shot. You can even evaluate it for 30 days. On the other hand if you are looking for open-source tools, AutoIT might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at Microsoft's [Coded-UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
However, notice it requires Visual Studio Ultimate or Premium.